# How to create and start a form Select field, without it being in the model?

Tags: django

I have reviewed many of the questions related to this topic, in this forum and in Spanish, I have followed the steps, and it does not work for me, on something that seems so simple, at first. I have **Django 2.2.6** with a form that needs the selected value of a Select field, which is not in the model, and acquires a list of values (tuples of two) created from the view.

Upon entering the form, throw this error: **"__init __ () received an unexpected keyword argument 'carpetas'"**, in the **FotoArtForm** class, in the **super ()** line.
This is my code:

**models.py**

```
class FotoArt(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='fotos/articulos/', null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['nombre']
        verbose_name = _('Foto Artículo')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Fotos Artículos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detalle-fotoArt', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**views.py**

```
class FotoArtActualizar(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = FotoArt
    form_class = FotoArtForm 
    Ruta = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'fotos', 'articulos')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(FotoArtActualizar, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['carpetas'] = self.get_folders_list(self.Ruta)
        return kwargs

    def get_folders_list(self, ruta):
        foldersList = []
        for _, listaSubDir, _ in os.walk(ruta):
            for dName in listaSubDir:
                foldersList.append((dName, dName))
        return foldersList
```

**forms.py**

```
class FotoArtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    guardar_en_carpeta = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FotoArtForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.foldersList = kwargs.pop('carpetas', None)

    self.fields['guardar_en_carpeta'].choices = self.foldersList

    class Meta:
        model = FotoArt
        fields = ['nombre', 'guardar_en_carpeta', 'foto']
```

**fotoArt_form.html**

```
{% extends 'catalogo/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Crear/Actualizar Fotos Artículos</h2>
    <hr/>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}

        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <label class="input-group-text font-weight-bold" for="inputCarpeta">Guardar en carpeta</label>
          </div>
          {{ form.guardar_en_carpeta.errors }}
          {{ form.guardar_en_carpeta }}
        </div>

        {{ form.foto.errors }}
        <strong>{{ form.foto.label_tag }}</strong>
        {{ form.foto }}

        <div class="form-group row my-2">
           <label for="nombreFoto" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"><strong>Nombre</strong></label>
            {{ form.nombre.errors }}
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               {{ form.nombre }}
           </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea why I get this error?

Perhaps, you should make another approach to pass the list of folders (choices) to the field save_in_folder of the form; instead of overwriting the get_form_kwargs () method, I could overwrite the get_context_data () method and pass it a context ['folders_list'], but then I can't control the value of the save_in_folder selector to use it in another field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the `carpetas` field in the `FotoArtForm.Meta.fields` but you're passing the data for that via form hence the error from the `FotoArtForm` initializer as `carpetas` is not a valid named argument.

You need to reverse the statements to `pop`-out the `capetas` named argument so that the `ModelForm.__init__` is called without it:

```
class FotoArtForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.foldersList = kwargs.pop('carpetas', None)
        super(FotoArtForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. My mistake in thinking that kwargs can host any parameter; You need to extract the extra parameters before creating an instance. Thanks for the help.